# Seleccionar elementos de un tipo en html, pero no los que estén anidados del mismo tipo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Necesito seleccionar con **jQuery** todos los elementos `ul` que estén dentro de un `nav`, pero solo los que no tengan un ancestro del mismo tipo (`ul`).

En el siguiente ejemplo en html

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Se necesita obtener el `ul` principal, pero no el del sub-menu.

El codigo HTML puede ser este o puede ser otro. Ya que proviene de diferentes paginas.

**EDICION**

Lo que he intentado hasta ahora

```
$('nav ul').each(function(){
    // Quito los elementos del DOM y los añado a
    // un menu personalizado.
})
```

El problema es que me selecciona también los submenu y lo que deseo son solo los menus principales.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola Abraham, por favor, añade un [mcve] para que podamos ver qué has hecho hasta el momento y poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No hay una forma directa de hacerlo, así que hay que filtrar el resultado obtenido.

**Filtrando el resultado.** Usamos [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/), y vemos que no tenga [`.parents('ul')`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

```js
//Seleccionar todos los UL que son descendientes de NAV, pero que no tengan un ancestro UL
var uls = $('nav ul')
  .filter(function() {
    return !$(this).parents('ul').length;
  });


//Imprimir el resultado en consola
uls.each(function() {
  console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Otro ejemplo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**Selector personalizado.** Por comodidad, se puede crear un selector personalizado en jQuery. Después de definirlo, simplemente llamamos a `$('nav ul:sinAncestro(ul)')`:

```js
//Se define un selector personalizado
$.expr[':'].sinAncestro = function(elemento,i,selector){
    return !$(elemento).parents(selector[3]).length;
};


//Seleccionar todos los UL que son descendientes de NAV, pero que no tengan un ancestro UL
var uls = $('nav ul:sinAncestro(ul)');


//Imprimir el resultado en consola
uls.each(function() {
  console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Otro ejemplo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Eso es ! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que usar el selector `>` que hace referencia a los elementos hijos directos.

Después de los comentarios, he visto que lo que buscabas era tener un `ul` dentro de otro `ul` y que los estilos se aplicaran solamente a los elementos `ul` que fueran hijos directos.

Al cambiarle el color y ser una propiedad que se hereda de sus elementos padres, podremos solucionar el problema de la herencia poniendo el color por defecto a todos los `ul`.

Posteriormente modificar únicamente los elementos `ul` que sean hijos directos tal y como mostraba en el ejemplo original.

Ejemplo:

```js
$('nav > ul').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

```css
ul{
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Coloreado (ul hijo)</li>
    <li>Coloreado (ul hijo)</li>
    <li>Coloreado (ul hijo)</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Sin Colorear (ul nieto)</li>
      <li>Sin Colorear (ul nieto)</li>
      <li>Sin Colorear (ul nieto)</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: No. Lo que necesito es que no tome elementos `ul`, que ya estan dentro de otro `ul`

Comment: @AbrahamTS Mira mi nueva edición. He añadido solamente el valor por defecto a todos los ul y después he modificado los que nos interesaban.

Comment: El problema es que yo no controlo el html y el elemento `ul` si puede estar anidado dentro de un `div` por ejemplo. Mira la pregunta editada. Y gracias por todo.

Comment: @AbrahamTS Realmente la nueva edición simplemente era para que vieras el "problema" que hay con el tema de la herencia en cuanto a color se refiere. Sin embargo, el selector `nav > ul` te va a funcionar para todos los `ul` que sean hijos directos. En caso de que sean "nietos", da igual que estén dentro de un `div` o de otro `ul`, no les aplicarán esos estilos.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción bastante sencilla es usar la función `not()` de jQuery para excluir los `ul` hijos de otros `ul`:

```js
$("nav ul").not("ul ul").css("border", "solid 1px red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que estaba esperando, pero la de @Woody tambien es correcta y soluciona el problema, por eso la acepte. De todas formas +1 por tu respuesta, que tambien es correcta

Comment: @AbrahamTS aunque tengas una respuesta estaría bien que editaras tu pregunta añadiendo algo de código con lo que habías intentado. Así te quedará una buena pregunta de calidad y posiblemente te quiten los negativos que has recibido

Comment: He editado mi pregunta con lo que habia intentado cuando la hice. Por cierto al probar tu respuesta me di cuenta de que no hace falta usar el constructor de `$()` dentro del not, se puede usar `.not('ul ul')` directamente. Pero igual es exelente. Gracias

Comment: Tienes razón, no hace falta el `$()` y queda más limpio el código sin él. Creo que lo he arrastrado de una prueba anterior.

Answer (score -1):

Para seleciona los elementos `ul` que contengan la palabra 'Lista' usa `:contains`:

```
$("ul li:contains('Lista')").each(function(){ $(this).css('color', 'yellow'); });
```

Y para el primer elemento usa `:first`:

```
 $('nav ul:first').each(function(){ $(this).css('color', 'yellow'); });
```

En esos ejemplos lo que se haría es poner el texto de color amarillo.

Comment: ¿Cómo resolvería esta respuesta el objetivo del OP?

Comment: $("ul li:contains('Lista')").each(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
});

Comment: $('nav ul:first').each(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
 });

Comment: Hola @EstAndromeda te recomendaría agregaras una descripción de lo que realizaría el código.saludos.